# Change of orientation causes app to crash

Tags: android, orientation

In a Tic-Tac-Toe app I am creating, I have set up an alternative screen view to handle a change in orientation.

My onCreate() method in my main Java file looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information); 
    mHumanScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_score);
    mComputerScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.computer_score);
    mTieScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tie_score);

    mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

    mBoardView = (BoardView) findViewById(R.id.board); 
    mBoardView.setGame(mGame); 
    mBoardView.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        startNewGame();
    else {
        mGame.setBoardState(savedInstanceState.getCharArray("board"));
        mGameOver = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mGameOver");
        mInfoTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("info"));
        mHumanWins = savedInstanceState.getInt("mHumanWins");
        mComputerWins = savedInstanceState.getInt("mComputerWins");
        mTies = savedInstanceState.getInt("mTies");
        mTurn = savedInstanceState.getChar("mTurn");
        mFirstMove = savedInstanceState.getChar("mFirstMove");
    }
    displayScores();
}
```

I then have two methods to handle the restoring and saving of states, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putCharArray("board", mGame.getBoardState());
    outState.putBoolean("mGameOver", mGameOver);
    outState.putInt("mHumanWins",  Integer.valueOf(mHumanWins));
    outState.putInt("mComputerWins", Integer.valueOf(mComputerWins));
    outState.putInt("mTies",  Integer.valueOf(mTies));
    outState.putCharSequence("info", mInfoTextView.getText());
    outState.putChar("mTurn", mTurn);
    outState.putChar("mFirstMove", mFirstMove);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mGame.setBoardState(savedInstanceState.getCharArray("board"));
    mGameOver = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mGameOver");
    mInfoTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("info"));
    mHumanWins = savedInstanceState.getInt("mHumanWins");
    mComputerWins = savedInstanceState.getInt("mComputerWins");
    mTies = savedInstanceState.getInt("mTies");
    mTurn = savedInstanceState.getChar("mTurn");
    mFirstMove = savedInstanceState.getChar("mFirstMove");
}
```

Everything way fine until I reprogrammed the game so that instead of X and O characters appearing on the board, pictures representing Xs and Os would appear. Doing this required me to implement a TouchListener. The game runs perfectly in vertical mode, but as soon as the orientation changes it crashes immediately. I don't even get to see the flipped screen change. If I view the horizontal layout in the layout-land main.xml file, it looks fine. I just can't get close to accessing it when it is actually running without the app crashing.

I'm a total newbie so have no idea what is causing this or what relevant information to post for more help. Does anyone have any advice?

**Edit - This is the LogCat error log: Whilst the program crashes upon orientation change on an actual device, in the emulator it crashes as soon as the program is run**

```
03-22 00:27:31.739: E/Trace(1042): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 00:27:31.739: W/Trace(1042): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-22 00:27:31.739: W/Trace(1042): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-22 00:27:31.749: W/Trace(1042): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-22 00:27:31.789: W/Trace(1042): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-22 00:27:31.789: W/Trace(1042): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-22 00:27:31.909: D/AndroidRuntime(1042): Shutting down VM
03-22 00:27:31.909: W/dalvikvm(1042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.joe.tictactoe/edu.joe.tictactoe.AndroidTicTacToeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at edu.joe.tictactoe.AndroidTicTacToeActivity.resetButtons(AndroidTicTacToeActivity.java:194)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at edu.joe.tictactoe.AndroidTicTacToeActivity.displayScores(AndroidTicTacToeActivity.java:311)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at edu.joe.tictactoe.AndroidTicTacToeActivity.onCreate(AndroidTicTacToeActivity.java:93)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-22 00:27:31.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     ... 11 more
03-22 00:27:32.211: D/dalvikvm(1042): GC_CONCURRENT freed 351K, 17% free 2438K/2908K, paused 109ms+3ms, total 288ms
```

**Edit 2: displayScores() and resetButtons() code:**

```
192 public void resetButtons()
193 {
194     for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
195     {
196         mBoardButtons[i].setText("");                       
197         mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);              
198         mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
199     }
200 }

304 private void displayScores() {
305     mHumanScoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanWins));
306     mComputerScoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mComputerWins));
307     mTieScoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mTies));
308
309
310     char [] temp = mGame.getBoardState();
311     resetButtons();
312
313     for (int i = 0; i < TicTacToeGame.BOARD_SIZE; i++)
314         if (temp [i] != TicTacToeGame.OPEN_SPOT) setMove(temp [i], i);
315 }
```

**Edit 3: Problem solved
Originally, the board used buttons which were filled in with either the character x or o. I removed these to use icons, but forgot to remove the resetButtons() line and the code. It was trying to reset something which no longer exists.**

Comment: Well, first of all, when the orientation changes, the activity will be destroyed and recreate so I guess you're getting a null pointer error. Perhaps you could post the error log?

Comment: How can I find the error log?

Comment: well, If you're using Eclipse here is the official guide. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: what ever before resetButtons is null. So you get null.resetButtons

Comment: does it crash if you start it with your phone in landscape, or only when you switch while the activity is open?

Comment: @user1853479: Fascinating point, I hadn't noticed that. NO, it does not crash if it starts in landscape. It is only crashing upon change of orientation.

Comment: post your code for displayScores()

Comment: can you show us resetButtons() and displayScores() and identify where lines 194 and 311 are?

Comment: Post your code from `displayScores()`

Comment: I've added the code and am sorry to say I've wasted all your time. I removed the buttons to create a gameboard that I could insert pictures on to, to represent the x and o. However, I forgot to remove the command to resetButtons(), and therefore of course the app locked up as there was nothing left to remove. Changed it, works fine now.

Comment: Sorry this was such a poor mistake. Thank you all for your very, VERY quick and informative help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all who helped in the comments with this. I wouldn't have known where to look otherwise.

Originally, the board used buttons which were initialised in onCreate() and filled in with either the character x or o as the game progressed.

I removed these buttons, drew a grid and used coordinates to place pictures to represent x and o. However, I forgot to remove the command to resetButtons(), which meant when the app launched it was trying to clear something which didn't exist. With this code removed, everything works perfectly.